# Excel/VBA - Fill color of a cell in pivot table according to column value

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that the source is a table on another sheet. The source table looks like this:

| Client | Type of income | Value | Month | Control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Residential | 1000 | January | Paid |
| A | Commercial | 2000 | February | Not paid |
| B | Residential | 2000 | February | Not paid |
| C | Commercial | 1500 | February | Paid |
| D | Consulting | 5000 | March | Paid |

The pivot table is set like this:

Column - Month
Row - Client
Value - Sum of value

| Client | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1000 | 2000 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 2000 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1500 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 5000 |

Now I want to fill the color of the cells based on the column "Control" - that is not on the Pivot table.
Every cell that is "not paid", I want it to be red.

Is this possible? I tried using conditional formatting, but without success.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way to color code data in a pivot table if it can't be done using conditional formatting, because after that, the only option remaining is VBA.

**You can achieve your goal by putting the column "Control" in the filter section of the pivot table.** This would also take care of the problem that would pop up if you have a paid and an unpaid bill by the same client in the same month.

My recommendation is to structure the pivot table in such a manner that you see paid and unpaid as categories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm now using the "control" as a row, and each client has rows that show "paid" and "unpaid". The thing is that I want to use the "type of income" as a row, so I won't have the problem of having paid and unpaid in the same cell. That's why I wanted to use colors to show me if "Control" is set to "paid" or "unpaid".
If I double click on a cell, I can see the details showing the "control" information. That's why I thought that I would be able to do that using VBA, but I don't know how.

Comment: I made and example: This is the table [link](https://imgur.com/efzLm22) and this is how I want the Pivot Table to look like [link](https://imgur.com/kzvPvxJ).