# VBA Begginer - Set multiple PivotItems in a range

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, pivotitem

I'm trying to set a range so I can automatically add background color to specific cells. I'm writing a code, that is not completed, but I'm stuck with something.

I can color all single cells that has value and from just one kind of "type"... I have multiple "types" and I wanted to reference them all!!

My code is like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable14")
Set rng1 = pt.DataBodyRange
Set rng2 = pt.PivotFields("Type").PivotItems("Residential").DataRange

For Each rng In Intersect(rng1, rng2)
If rng.Value > 0 Then
rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
Next
```

How can I reference all PivotItems inside PivotFields "Type"???

I tried something like:

`Set rng2 = pt.PivotFields("Type").PivotItems("(All)").DataRange`

But that didn't work.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand your query. Can you share a sample screenshot (Before & After)?

Comment: It's how I'm trying to pull this up [link](https://superuser.com/q/1613485/1256415)

Comment: Do you mean that each type should have same colour? For example Residential - Red, Commercial - Yellow etc etc?

Comment: All cells that have value must be yellow (and blanks without color)... I'm using PivotItems because that was the only way I could select individual cells (instead of everyone, including Totals and subtotals)

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is this [link - mrexcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/excel-vba-fill-color-of-a-cell-in-pivot-table-according-to-column-value-in-source-table.1157089/#post-5611793) and I asked the same question here [link - superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1613485/1256415) and here [link - stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486414/excel-vba-fill-color-of-a-cell-in-pivot-table-according-to-column-value/65487983#65487983)... but I just can't get to work